# str_replace won't replace strings

Tags: php, iframe, str-replace

my code isn't replacing, and I must have missed something.  It's simple. what did I miss?

```
echo "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/";
echo str_replace("http://youtube.com/watch?v=", "", $row['videourl']);
echo "/\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

What I get as a result looks like this:

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QWrxbiBeds/"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="fitvid890584"></iframe>
```

help?

Comment: Well, I changed the source (haystack) to be http instead - the results were similar:

`<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QWrxbiBeds/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="fitvid473769"></iframe>`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your video URL has https in it but you're looking for http

```
echo str_replace("http://youtube.com/watch?v=", "", $row['videourl']);
```

vs

```
echo str_replace("https://youtube.com/watch?v=", "", $row['videourl']);
```